# Deploy Vue frontend with Node.js backend to Firebase

Tags: node.js, vue.js, firebase-hosting

I've got a Vue test project with Node backend.

The project structure looks like this:

[image]

The main.js in the src folder contains this code:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import "./assets/tailwind.css";
import vue3GoogleLogin from "vue3-google-login";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

import piniaPluginPersistedstate from "pinia-plugin-persistedstate";

const pinia = createPinia();
pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate);

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);
app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
  clientId:
    "my-id",
});
app.mount("#app");
```

And the index.js for the backend part looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {OAuth2Client} = require("google-auth-library");
const client = new OAuth2Client("my-id");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/api/google-login", async (req, res) => {
    const data = await client.verifyIdToken({idToken: req.body.token});
    res.status(200).json(data.getPayload())
});
app.listen(4001, () => {
    console.log('Server is running!');
})
```

When I deploy it to Firebase the backend part is mot working. I only run `npm run dev` on the frontend folder and I think the port number should be changed as well.

How is it possible to deploy it to Firebase?